# Is there a way to manage huge many import statements in Python?

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I am working on a Flask-RESTFul API where I have so many import statements in my `app.py` file as below.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api

from apis.ChambAvail import ChambAvail
from apis.ChambAvailBal import ChambAvailBal
from apis.ChambTwInhibit import ChambTwInhibit
from apis.CurrentWip import CurrentWip
from apis.Detail import Detail
from apis.IncomingWip import IncomingWip
from apis.Info import Info
from apis.Manage import Manage
from apis.MfCount import MfCount
from apis.OtherHold import OtherHold
from apis.PqeDue import PqeDue
from apis.QualInhibit import QualInhibit
from apis.ReleaseBef import ReleaseBef
from apis.RfInhibit import RfInhibit
from apis.SketchDetailedLot import SketchDetailedLot
from apis.SketchLotDetail import SketchLotDetail
from apis.SketchMainDetail import SketchMainDetail
from apis.SketchMainRC import SketchMainRC
from apis.SketchDesignInfo import SketchDesignInfo
from apis.SketchOneDetail import SketchOneDetail
from apis.SketchOneLotDetail import SketchOneLotDetail
from apis.SketchOneMain import SketchOneMain
from apis.SketchOneNearestLot import SketchOneNearestLot
from apis.SketchTimeList import SketchTimeList
from apis.SketchWsgList import SketchWsgList
from apis.TakeEquipDetail import TakeEquipDetail
from apis.TakeEquipLotDetail import TakeEquipLotDetail
from apis.TakeEquipMain import TakeEquipMain
from apis.TakeOneDetail import TakeOneDetail
from apis.TakeOneEquipData import TakeOneEquipData
from apis.TakeOneMain import TakeOneMain
from apis.TakeOneRADetail import TakeOneRADetail
from apis.UpdBufInputCapacity import UpdBufInputCapacity
from apis.UpdEohInputCapacity import UpdEohInputCapacity
from dbmanager import datasource
from logmanager.setlogger import logger
from utils import config_reader

env = 'test'
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

api.add_resource(SketchMainRC, '/SketchMainrc')
api.add_resource(SketchDesignInfo, '/SketchDesigninfo')
api.add_resource(SketchWsgList, '/Sketchwsglist')
api.add_resource(SketchMainDetail, '/Sketchmaindetail')
api.add_resource(SketchLotDetail, '/Sketchlotdetail')
api.add_resource(SketchOneMain, '/SketchOneMain')
api.add_resource(SketchOneDetail, '/SketchOnedetail')
api.add_resource(SketchOneLotDetail, '/SketchOnelotdetail')
api.add_resource(SketchOneNearestLot, '/SketchOnenearestlot')
api.add_resource(SketchDetailedLot, '/Sketchdetailedlot')
api.add_resource(SketchTimeList, '/Sketchtimelist')
api.add_resource(TakeEquipMain, '/TakeequipMain')
api.add_resource(TakeEquipDetail, '/Takeequipdetail')
api.add_resource(TakeEquipLotDetail, '/Takeequiplotdetail')
api.add_resource(TakeOneMain, '/TakeOneMain')
api.add_resource(TakeOneDetail, '/TakeOnedetail')
api.add_resource(TakeOneRADetail, '/TakeOneradetail')
api.add_resource(TakeOneEquipData, '/TakeOneequipData')
api.add_resource(ChambAvail, '/chambavail')
api.add_resource(ChambAvailBal, '/chambavailbal')
api.add_resource(ChambTwInhibit, '/chambtwinhibit')
api.add_resource(CurrentWip, '/currentwip')
api.add_resource(IncomingWip, '/incomingwip')
api.add_resource(Detail, '/detail')
api.add_resource(Manage, '/manage')
api.add_resource(MfCount, '/mfcount')
api.add_resource(OtherHold, '/otherhold')
api.add_resource(PqeDue, '/pqedue')
api.add_resource(QualInhibit, '/qualinhibit')
api.add_resource(ReleaseBef, '/releasebef')
api.add_resource(RfInhibit, '/rfinhibit')
api.add_resource(Info, '/info')
api.add_resource(InputCapacity, '/inputcapacity')
api.add_resource(InputCapacity, '/inputcapacity')

app.ls_sf_db_env = 'test'
app.ls_config = config_reader.get_config('test')

# Initialise the connection pool
datasource.initial_all_fab_engine(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logger.info('Starting the server')
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

Below is my project structure.
[image]

These are just some of the APIs I completed & there are 100 more. I am new to Python, particularly to Flask-RESTFul API Development. I have separate classes for each API, I thought code looks cleaner that way. But in my `app.py` file, these import statements are piling up. Is there a better way to add/manage these import statements & also the add.resource() statements in a better way in my `app.py` file ? Could anyone let me know if there is a way I can import all these statements differently & keep my `app.py` cleaner ?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you add some information about the structure of your project? As Python derives modules and packages from the folder structure, this would help to give an insightful answer.

Comment: Are you aware that Python does not restrict you to one class per module? A series of ``from a.b.X import X``, ``from a.b.Y import Y`` should usually just be ``from a.b import X, Y, ...``.

Comment: I added the project structure.
@MisterMiyagi Yes I am aware of that. But I have more than 200 APIs to write. Keeping all of them in a single .py file is a bit confusing.
I don't have all the API classed in a.b package. I have a main package `apis` and inside that I have one .py file for each API.

Comment: It also appears as if your structure actually contains substructures. For example, ``apis.SketchDetailedLot``, ``apis.SketchLotDetail``, ``apis.SketchMainDetail``, ... should maybe all be children of ``apis.Sketch``. That would then just be ``from apis import Sketch`` and ``api.add_resource(Sketch.MainRC, '/SketchMainrc')``. You might even want to go so far as to allow the parent modules to add their child resources automatically, given an ``app``.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi There are no sub packages inside each package. All of the packages you see are inside the main package `com` and all of them contain `.py` files.

Comment: @Metadata ``a.b`` was an example, just like ``X`` and ``Y`` – substitute ``apis`` and ``SketchDetailedLot``, ... in your case. I realise that you *have* one file per API, what I'm asking is whether you are aware that you do *not have to have* one file per API.

Comment: Yes I do. Thats what I explained in the another comment above. Please check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do some path-based magic.

The following snippet will list all `.py` files in the `apis/` subdir, import them as modules, extract a class that is named same as the file, and register it under `/ClassName` endpoint.

```
from importlib import import_module
from pathlib import Path

HERE = Path(__file__).parent

for api_class_file in HERE.glob("apis/*.py"):
    # apis/ChambAvail.py -> ChambAvail
    api_class_name = api_class_file.stem
    if api_class_name.startswith("__"):
        # skip special files such as __init__ and __main__
        continue

    # equivalent to "import apis.ChambAvail"
    api_module = import_module(f"apis.{api_class_name}")
    # equivalent to "apis.ChambAvail.ChambAvail
    api_class = getattr(api_module, api_class_name)
    api.add_resource(api_class, f"/{api_class_name}")
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 60, in <module>
    api.add_resource(api_class, '/{api_class_name}'.format(api_class_name=api_class_name.lower()))
  File "\PycharmProjects\FE_IOS_API\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 392, in add_resource
    self._register_view(self.app, resource, *urls, **kwargs)
  File "\PycharmProjects\FE_IOS_API\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 430, in _register_view
    resource.mediatypes = self.mediatypes_method()  # Hacky
AttributeError: 'method-wrapper' object has no attribute 'mediatypes'`

Comment: Fixed it..The file: `__init__.py` is creating the issue. I added an IF condition to check the class name and add it if it is not `__init__.py` This `IF-Condition => if api_class_name != '__init__':` goes after the `getattr()` statement. Can you add it to your answer.